# ListDensityPlot and interpolation order

Tags: plotting

I am working on a project that takes arrays of data and visualizes them using `ListDensityPlot`. I noticed, when I imported an array from a CSV file, the last column was not being shown. On further inspection the last row also isn't. The array itself is of size X x Y, but when I try to plot using `InterpolationOrder -> 0`, it is dropping the last row and column, and plotting an array of dimensions (X-1) x (Y-1). This is changed, however, when I use InterpolationOrder -> 1 or remove the `InterpolationOrder` option from the arguments.

For an example, take the array {{1,2},{3,4}}.  This gives two plots as shown below

[image: Listdensityplot]

As you can see, this first one is clearly not the plot I want, but even if it were, it is in the wrong format. This example shows that the interpolated `ListDensityPlot` is not treating the last row and column the same way as the non-interpolated. Is there a way to make a plot that behave nicely without having to drop the last row/column when using `InterpolationOrder -> 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `Interpolation -> 0`, then I assume you want a step-like representation of the data. If that's the case, I would recommend either `ArrayPlot` or `MatrixPlot`.

For a 2x2 matrix, what you're seeing is the expected output of `InterpolationOrder -> 0`. If you try `ListLinePlot[{1, 2}, InterpolationOrder -> 0]`, you can see that it produces an infinitely narrow discontinuity on the right side that is impossible to display in a density plot. This means that your density plot will always be of a size x-1 * y-1.

```
MatrixPlot[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}/4]
```

[image: Matrix plot of poster's data.]

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed.